# how to we create the events in the VSTO 2010 c#

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto

I have developed the VSTO addin in c# and now i want to add event to SheetChanged,SheetSelectionChanged,WorkBookActivate, WorkBookDeactivate. How can I achieve this?
Can I use the same Commandbar event to do this? Or is there any difference between the commandbars and VSTO event handlers?Please help me in this.

I am using .net 4.0 developing the addin for Office 2010.
Please someone help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these events are available in VSTO directly why do you want to use the same through Commandbar?

Keep it simple and easy by using VSTO events if they are available. I believe they are same in underneath, VSTO been a managed wrapper on COM objects.

Comment: so I can retain the same events? I am using the Ribbon(Visual Designer) but not the Ribbon XML, Can I achieve the same? Can I use it pro grammatically to create all customization like context menu and all that?

Comment: Yes indeed, Ribbon visual designer is just to make things easier.